# How to correctly set p:autoComplete width to fill a panel

Tags: css, primefaces, autocomplete, width

How can I set the autoComplete width to fill the panel correctly?

[image: autoComplete]

As you can see, using:

```
.ui-autocomplete input {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

will put the arrow out of the panel

EDIT: panelGrid

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3" style="border: hidden; width: 100%" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                        <p:panelGrid>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Item name" for="haveName" />
                            <br/>
                            <p:autoComplete id="haveName" effect="fade" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:panelGrid>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Paint" for="havePaint" />
                            <br/>
                            <p:autoComplete id="havePaint" effect="fade" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:panelGrid>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Certification" for="haveCert" />
                            <br/>
                            <p:autoComplete id="haveCert" effect="fade" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panelGrid>
```

EDIT2: this is what happens when I set `style="width: 100%"` in the autoComplete tag:

[image: autoComplete width]

EDIT3: this happens when I combine both:

[image: both css]

Comment: To fill **what** panel?

Comment: I have added the panelGrid code of my .xhtml page

Comment: But **why** do you size the input in the autocomplete and not the autocomplete itself then?

Comment: Check my second edit.

Comment: And what if you combine both? It is all plain css... Nothing jsf or PrimeFaces specifically. And the client-side generated html is way more important here.

Comment: Edited first post.

Comment: **then play with the css**... make the one a little less then 100%, or do some 'calc'... 100% on one and calc (100%-79px) on the other makes it perfectly fit for me in the PrimeFaces showcase... All just css, easy to try with a browser developer tool

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity And it is 'ui-autocomplete'...!!! Please be careful with what you post.

Comment: Can I refer to the `input` by using `.ui-autocomplete` only in a css style text?

Comment: ??? No, ofcourse not... the `ui-autocomplete` is the parent of the `input`. So you need two css selectors and most likely in two css rules... All basic css...  http://htmldog.com/guides/css/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another simple question: I set the font-size using `ui-outputlabel`, but it won't change anything. Is that because all labels are referring to two classes at the same time?

Comment: New questions in new topics... And this is most likely a css-specificity thing to... Read that article carfefully.

Answer (score 7):

If someone else is wondering how to achieve a full responsive autocomplete component on:

PrimeNg version: 4.0.3
Angular: 4.0.3

For me the only possible thing on earth that worked was a combination of this styles :

```
 [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" class="p-autocomplete"
```

with the following definition of the css:

```
.p-autocomplete{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Hooope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

In version **primeng 11.3.2**, you have to combine [style] and [inputStyle]:

```
[style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"
```

If you use the attribute `[multiple] =" true "`, wrap the `<p-autoComplete> </p-autoComplete>` in a `span` with the class `p-fluid`

```
<span class="p-fluid">
    <p-autoComplete class="mdb-autocomplete" field="email" placeholder="Search user"
        [(ngModel)]="item_ac" [suggestions]="filterAC"[multiple]="true"
        [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" 
        (completeMethod)="onCompleteAC($event)" 
        (onSelect)="onSelectAC($event)" (onUnselect)="onUnselectAC($event)">
        <ng-template let-item_ac pTemplate="item">
            <div class="div-item-ac">
            
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-autoComplete>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It Worked for me this way

```
.ui-autocomplete{
width: 100% !important;}
.ui-autocomplete-input{
width: 90% !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the version 13, you can use the fluid class on your span tag like this

`<span class="p-fluid"> <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" [suggestions]="filteredCountries" (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)" field="name" [multiple]="true"> </p-autoComplete> </span>`

then your autocomplete will take the 100% of width

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `!important` css declaration.**

PrimeNG ULTIMA 5.2.0, PrimeNG 5.2.0

Setting the style `width` for `.md-autocomplete` when your `<p-autoComplete>` element is children of an `ui-inputgroup`

will cause the `width` being overwritten by the definition `body .ui-inputgroup *[class^="md-"]`.

Take a look how the `width` in `.md-autocomplete` gets overwritten (at bottom):

[image: p-autocomplete width gets **overwritten**]

You should make you definition `!important` Take a look how the `width` in `.md-autocomplete` gets **not overwritten** (at bottom):

[image: p-autocomplete width set to important]

And additionally the style attribute of the element `p-autoComplete` should look like:
`[style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"`.

Comment: Sure a better selector does not work instead of using !important

Answer (score 0):

In PF 6.1 `<p:autocomplete>` has a size attribute for this, setting it to "100%" works for me.

Comment: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [100%] of type [class java.lang.String] to [int]

Comment: Setting it to for example 10 does not seem to work either.